# Talend How to Convert String to Date for SAP integration using tMap

Tags: date, input, talend, saprfc

1. I need to pass a date (billing) to the RFC, but I am not sure how to map using tmap. How to set it up (see screenshots).

   [image: job]

   [image: map editor]

   [image: output mapping]

   [image: tsapinput]
2. I need to run this job daily (M-F) and I am not sure how to automate the date input
3. For the date input, I thought of using a joblet, but I can't find it in Talend. Most screenshots shows the Joblets in the same window as job designs and metadata, but I don't have it. Seen Joblet image.

   [image: No Joblet]

As you might have guessed, I am very new to Talend.

Comment: joblet is available in enterprise edition of talend. what is the challenge you are facing when you use date - are you not able to link input date with output table date in tmap?

Comment: SAP date format is: YYYYMMDD  a.k.a ISO date format. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the clarification for the Joblets and data formatting

Answer (score 0):

Use a tMap, and inside it use the function TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd", sap_data.date) in the expression field where you want the output. Also, note that the output type must be Date. The Date Pattern in the type definition (on the bottom of the tmap) is irrelevant.

Something like that:

[image]

Comment: Starting job Chargebacks at 16:30 09/10/2014.

[statistics] connecting to socket on port 4014
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tSAPInput_1
com.sap.conn.jco.ConversionException: (122) JCO_ERROR_CONVERSION: Cannot convert a value of '7/31/2014' from type java.lang.String to DATE at field I_BUDAT

Comment: I don't know how to post a new screenshot of my tmap

Comment: My tmap is setup like yours.  TalendDate.parseDate("yyyyMMdd",outFromSAP.I_BUDAT) . I also tried TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd",outFromSAP.I_BUDAT)

Comment: this second parameter should be a date (from code view):   importParameterList_tSAPInput_1.setValue("I_BUDAT", "7/31/2014"); // "input_single"

Comment: have you tried changing the pattern inside the parseDate to "dd/MM/yyyy" ?